# Need to pass this SQL code to spark syntax

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

Having a hard time passing this code to just pyspark syntax, without using spark.sql

`TableD = spark.sql("SELECT Region, SUM(moneyspent)/count(distinct id) as avgspent FROM finaldatatable as Data GROUP BY Region ORDER BY avgspent desc ")
TableD.show()`

Please help, really stuck here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- moneyspent: double (nullable = true)


>>> df
.groupBy(F.col("region"))
.agg((F.sum(F.col("moneyspent"))/F.countDistinct(F.col("id"))).alias("avgspent"))
.orderBy(F.col("avgspent"),ascending=False)
.show()
```

Comment: It returns me this error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

moneyspent is double, id is integer and region is string so i don't get it, why doesn't it allows me to do the division.

Comment: May be some of your builtin python functions are conflicting ..try to prefix spark functions as ```F.``` for examples ```F.sum``` for sum function.

Comment: I did the prefix with F. and it works! Do not know exactly why but it works. Thanks you!

Comment: Reason is python has some of same methods as spark..may by default it is invoking those python methods